# unicorn timeout handling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, unicorn

I'm wondering what is the best way to track unicorn timeouts from my app.

There are some bits of the app which are slow and they currently timeout quietly. I could increase the timeout but that is shoving the problem under the carpet. Ideally, I would like to get an airbrake notification or something of that effect. I'm not looking for a performance guide, just a way to efficiently and reliably get informed about timeouts.

How have other people handled timeouts from their rails app using unicorn? scan the nginx error log? plug in a handler in unicorn config? handler in nginx config?

[Ubuntu 12.04+nginx+unicorn+rails 3.2+ruby 1.9.3]

Comment: Did you find an answer?  We are using Rack::Timeout.

Comment: Workaround was to scan the nginx logs for 503 (or some 50X, cant recall) status and see from there. Kinda meets the objective in some odd way.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be inclined to create an account on [New Relic](http://newrelic.com), use their `newrelic_rpm` gem and collect performance data related to this issue in their web application. NR offer a free account level which is useful for this situation.

The benefit of using this somewhat lazy instrumentation method is twofold: no requirement for a custom instrumentation implementation in your application; and no need to check your downstream webserver logs for 503 server errors.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer! But i'm not looking to introduce a new service or an app at the moment. I looking for a specific hook into the timeout capture of unicorn

Comment: Then perhaps you should look at the 'configurator' and 'tuning' sections of the Unicorn manual.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the ['configurator' section](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/Unicorn/Configurator.html) of the Unicorn manual website. There's a series of items around backlog and timeouts which should give you the control you need.

Comment: I've gone thru those pages already. They do not talk about handling timeouts as far as I understand. They talk about controlling timeout period only.

Comment: Have you added an `ensure` block to the relevant parts of your application code which times out?

Comment: If I knew all the slow parts I would just fix those parts and not care about timeout n all. I'm specifically only interested in handling timeout by getting informed.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a middleware that logs this, just before the unicorn is getting killed (logs are not guaranteed to be processed if what you do in the middleware is slower than the 1 second interval, but you should still get a decent amount of visibility)

```
# config/initializers/log_unicorn_timeout.rb
class LogUnicornTimeout
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    t = Thread.new do
      sleep(UNICORN_TIMEOUT - 1) # just before the timeout kicks in - 1
      unless Thread.current[:done]
        path = env["PATH_INFO"]
        query = env["QUERY_STRING"]
        Rails.logger.warn "Path: #{path} Query: #{query}"
      end
    end

    @app.call(env)
  ensure
    t[:done] = true
    t.run
  end
end
```

Then add the middleware above in your `application.rb`

`config.middleware.use 'LogUnicornTimeout'`